# Почему CLion видит только старую версию MinGW?

Tags: c++, clion

[image: Настройки компиляции. Выбор компилятора]

Собственно, я уже гуглил, но так и не понял, та ли у меня версия, и всё ли я скачал. В самой программе с GUI (`MinGW`) я установил (скачал) всевозможные пакеты, но они были архивами и они так и остались висеть в загрузках. 
Один пакет я разархивировал (`g++`) и засунул в папку `C:\MinGW`, но это не дало ровным счётом ничего. Сейчас качаю `cygwin`, но не уверен, что это поможет.
Вопрос возник из-за отсутствия функции `to_string` в пространстве имен `std` библиотеки `string`.

Comment: В службу поддержки Вы не пробовали обращаться?

Comment: Стоит попробовать.

Comment: Проблему решил, но с помощью cygwin. Плюнул на mingw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы скачали не то. Приведу ссылки на хорошие сборки, которые уже давно и хорошо развиваются, как правило имеют свежие версии компилятора. Это тут - для [Win x32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.3.0/), для [Win x64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/6.3.0/). А вот далее уже нужно будет самостоятельно определиться с моделью потоков, там есть и `win`, и `posix`. Я бы рекомендовал второе, хотя говорят для `Windows` - первые работают быстрее, но в ущерб полной поддержки `С++11`.

Answer (score -2):

`MinGW` не включает в себя библиотеку `string` с пространством имен `std`. 
Это поддерживает `cygwin`. Стоит просто скачать `cygwin` с [официального сайта](https://www.cygwin.com/) и в настройках `CLion` выбрать папку `cygwin`(куда были установлены все файлы) вместо `MinGW` и перезагрузить проект.

Comment: Бред полнейший! MinGW включает всю библиотеку STL

Comment: включает, не спорю, но именно to_string там нет(в данной версии).

Comment: значит нужно ставить свой тулчейн(ы), в ответе я указал рабочие примеры

Comment: спасибо, на будущее сохраню, но пока всё отлично с cygwin